# Parent prepend SCSS

Tags: sass

I am trying to place my selectors inside a parent.

```
#top{
    /*! Single Product Page*/
    &.single-product .title_container{
        display: none;
    }

    .product_title_single{
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        h1{margin-bottom: 10px;}
    }
   ------------so on..
}
```

However compiled css combine all comments into parent selected separately.

```
#top {
    /*Slider customisation*/
    /* End Slider customisation*/
    /*Text horiziontal Ruler*/
    /*Quick Finder*/
    /*Brand Logos*/
    /*Product Category Grid*/
    /*infobox*/
    /*News Archive Page*/
    /*Blog Archive Page Search*/

}
```

Rest of the code is fine, is it possible to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunately not.**

Your example above is a good one for explaining why, however.

As the processor works its way through nested selectors, it treats any properties or comments directly nested within the top-level selector as being associated with that top-level selector.

Consider this example, (which is basically yours with the addition of the `margin-top` and `padding-top` properties, and another line after the example comment):

```css
#top {
    margin-top: 0;

    /* a comment */

    &.single-product .title_container {
        display: none;
    }

    .product_title_single {
        margin-bottom: 40px;

        h1 {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    }

    padding-top: 0;
}
```

It compiles to this:

```css
#top {
    margin-top: 0;
    /* a comment */
    padding-top: 0;
}

#top.single-product .title_container{
    display: none;
}

#top .product_title_single {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#top .product_title_single h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Notice where `padding-top: 0;` ends up, even though it came after the nested selectors.

**The SCSS processor treats properties and comments as "children" of the nearest "parent" selector**, regardless of what precedes or follows them. It has no way of knowing that a comment is associated with any following nested selectors.

If you need your comments to remain associated with their nested selectors in the compiled output, you'll need to add the comments *inside* those child selectors:

```css
#top {
    margin-top: 0;

    &.single-product .title_container {
        /* a comment */
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This also doesn't accomplish your real goal, however, which is to have a comment that refers to multiple following selectors, not just a single one.

You may want to shift to thinking about these comments as being more valuable to you as pre-compilation reminders, instead of keeping them around in the compiled output.

If you take that approach, try using "silent comments" with `//` instead of `/* */` in your SCSS:

```js
#top {
    margin-top: 0;

    // a comment
    &.single-product .title_container {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Compiles to this (double-slash comments get removed during compilation):

```css
#top {
    margin-top: 0;
}

#top.single-product .title_container{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation, I think i will go with appending the parent with each selector. Comments are important as after deployment we need to modify CSS directly if required.